# Jsoup - select a table based on the value of two p tags within the same td

Tags: jsoup

I have a html which has multiple tables. I want to select few tables based on certain conditions.

I need to select the tables based on a tr tag that has two `<p>` tags. 
I want to check the values of both the `<p>` tags under the SAME tr tag.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p>ABCD</p>
<p>HELLO</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p>ABCD</p>
<p>BYE</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p>ABCD</p>
<p>HELLO</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am easily able to select one of the items by using

```
 for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {                        
        for (Element tds : table.select("td")) {
               tds.text().contains("ABCD");
               table.append(table.outerhtml);
         }
    }
 }
```

where table is a string builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `element.html()` (or `element.outerHtml()`) we can grab the String representation of the HTML code. Then we can combine multiple contains-verifications.

**Code**

```
StringBuilder tableBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
    String innerHtml = table.html();
    if(innerHtml.contains("ABCD") && innerHtml.contains("HELLO")) tableBuilder.append(table.outerHtml());
}

System.out.println(tableBuilder.toString());
```

If it is really important, that the two patterns are within the same `tr`tag I would introduce some flags, to mark matches, to avoid regular expressions:

```
StringBuilder tableBuilder = new StringBuilder();

boolean firstPatternFlag = false;
boolean secondPatternFlag = false;

tableloop:
for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
    for (Element trElement : table.select("tr")) {
        firstPatternFlag = false;
        secondPatternFlag = false;

        for (Element tdElement : trElement.select("td")) {
            if(tdElement.text().contains("ABCD")) firstPatternFlag=true;
            if(tdElement.text().contains("HELLO")) secondPatternFlag=true;
        }
        if(firstPatternFlag && secondPatternFlag){
            tableBuilder.append(table.outerHtml());
            continue tableloop;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

Specification in comments:

> i would like to uniquely check if  first `<p>` tag contains ABCD and
>   second `<p>` tag contains HELLO

```
StringBuilder tableBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
    Elements pElement = table.select("tr").first().select("p");
    if(pElement.size()>2 && pElement.get(0).text().contains("ABCD") && pElement.get(1).text().contains("HELLO")) tableBuilder.append(table.outerHtml());
}
```

**Update 2**

Only the first row?

> its not just the first one,but all. I have 2 column tables with
>   multiple rows. Evert `<tr>` tag has 2 `<td>` tags, each `<td>` tag has one
>   `<p>` tag. so i will need to check within the same `<tr>` the first `<p>`
>   inside the first `<td>` contains ABCD and the second `<p>` inside the
>   second `<td>` contains HELLO.

I assuming it was meant: ... and the *first* `<p>` inside the second `<td>`

So this would result in the following structure:

```
<table>
    [<tr>...</tr>]
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>ABCD</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>HELLO</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    [<tr>...</tr>]
</table>
```

So we have to test every row in every table. If at least two `<td>` elements are present, we check if the first two td elements contain at least one `<p>` tag and compare the textnodes.

**Code**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(...); //source not specified in question

StringBuilder tableBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (Element table : doc.select("table")) { // check every table
    for (Element tr : table.select("tr")) { // check every row

        Elements tdElements = tr.select("td");

        if (tdElements.size() < 2) { // row contains at least two <td> elements
            continue;
        }

        Elements firstTdPElements = tdElements.get(0).select("p");
        Elements secondTdPElements = tdElements.get(1).select("p");

        if (firstTdPElements.isEmpty() || secondTdPElements.isEmpty()) { // first and second <td> contain at least one <p> element
            continue;
        }

        // first p in first td contains "ABCD"
        // first p in second td contains "Hello"
        if (firstTdPElements.get(0).text().contains("ABCD")
                && secondTdPElements.get(0).text().contains("HELLO")) {
            tableBuilder.append(table.outerHtml());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, again this is something i have tried. But that is where im facing the issue. There are scenarios where sometimes ABCD and HELLO fall in the same tag. so i would like to uniquely check if <tr> first <p> tag contains ABCD and second <p> tag contains HELLO

Comment: See updated answer. Your requirements are still not complete: is it only the first row, that needs to be checked for the two `<p>` tags or all `<r>`-tags?

Comment: Ok so to be even clear, a little more complicated requirement, its not just the first one,but all. I have 2 column tables with multiple rows. Evert <tr> tag has 2 <td> tags, each <td> tag has one <p> tag. so i will need to check within the same <tr> the first <p> inside the first <td> contains ABCD and the second <p> inside the second <td> contains HELLO. Also when i parse there could be other tables without the above specification, just so that no null pointer exceptions occur. Thank you for your replies !

Comment: @NCoder `each <td> tag has one <p> tag ... and the second <p> inside the second <td> contains HELLO.` That is a totally different structure than stated in your question. Update your question with the proper structure and be precise this time.

Comment: @NCoder: see Update 2.